# How to make a grid on python (using matplotlib or other library)

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I want to do a grid on python. I know it's possible using `matplotlib`, but I do struggle.

The grid I want to obtain is like the one on this graph. This means 8 row, and 13 columns.

[image]

Comment: There's far more going on in that image than simply plotting a grid. This is too broad; you haven't given the necessary data, code or context to produce that figure.

Comment: I know that, I just wanted the grid for the moment. I'll try to do what's left on my own. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having access to the data to reproduce your figure (without grid), it's impossible to provide a working code to you. However, below is one basic example on how to do it. The trick here is to use major ticks at spacing of 1 ranging from 1 to 13 on the x-axis and ranging from 1 to 8 on y-axis. Then you need to turn on the grid using `plt.grid()` and use `linestyle='dotted'` to get the grid similar to what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(1, 14, 50)
y = np.random.randint(1, 9, 50)

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.xticks(range(1, 14));
plt.yticks(range(1, 9));
plt.grid(linestyle='dotted')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm new, I don't find the button to accept :/

Comment: You can click the grey check mark next to my answer

Comment: add `+ 0.5` to the x and y arrays to get the markers in the middle of the grid cells